# Summing Mongo Sub-documents' field

Tags: mongodb

Given the following database's collection:

```
> db.collection.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "results" : { "record" : { "price" : 100 } } }
{ "_id" : 2, "results" : { "record" : { "price" : 200 } } }
{ "_id" : 3, "results" : { "record" : { "price" : 300 } } }
```

How can I use aggregation (or map-reduce) to get the sum of each `results.record.price` field?

```
> db.collection.aggregate( {$group : { _id:"", "results.record.price" : {$sum : "$results.record.price"}}}, {$project:{_id: 0, "results.record.price" : "$results.record.price"}})
Error: Printing Stack Trace
    at printStackTrace (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37:15)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:897:9)
    at (shell):1:15
Mon Oct 28 20:15:24.065 aggregate failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: the group aggregate field name 'results.record.price' cannot be used because $group's field names cannot contain '
.'",
        "code" : 16414,
        "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:898
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
db.collection.aggregate({$group : {_id: "", total : {$sum: "$results.record.price"}}}, {$project: {_id: 0, total: 1}})
```

Comment: What does `_id: ""` mean? Thanks for help

Comment: @kevin `_id` is the group identifier. In that case, since it is constant, the empty string, every record processed will be merged into a single group, identified by that empty string. You could have used other constants, like `null`, `"a"` etc.

Comment: Could you please check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664748/summing-mongo-sub-document-array